# Data Loader cmd line

Tags: data-loader, commandline

I am getting this error when trying to authenticate into the cmd line interface for Data loader. I have read some previous threads on making sure Java and data loader are up to date. I have updated both but still get the error.

C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin>encrypt.bat -e password "C:\temp\key.txt"

[image]

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin>encrypt.bat -e <password> "C:\temp\key.txt"

Comment: Please type out or copy errors as *text*. Images are not very accessible.

Comment: What are the contents of your key.txt file, Allen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue.

I had a sting of text describing the key in in my key.txt file.